# Haskell standalone executable without using 'stack exec'

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

How would one go about creating an executable from a `stack` generated framework (`stack new myprog simple`)?

`myprog.cabal` shows `myprog` as executable that can be executed using `stack exec myprog`.

However: using `./myprog` will not work. Not unless I call `ghc --make src/Main.hs`. This works obviously and nicely embeds the modules, but now the executable is called `Main`.

Is there a way to have `stack` compile `myprog` as a complete executable that can be called from anywhere assuming the environmental path is set?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you may already be aware, `stack build` builds the executable, but then places it in a `stack`-specific path which can most easily be accessed using `stack exec`. However, there is another command: `stack install`, which then copies the executable to a convenient location. Normally the default location is in `~/.local/bin` (I think), but you can use `stack install --local-bin-path <PATH>` to copy the executable to `<PATH>`. For instance, use `stack install --local-bin-path .` to place the executable in your current working directory, or use `stack install --local-bin-path bin` to place it in your `./bin/` directory. You can then run the executable using `<PATH>/my-exe`.